# Python: can numba work with arrays of strings in nopython mode?

Tags: python, string, numba

I am using pandas 0.16.2, numpy 1.9.2 and numba 0.20.

Is there any way to get numba to support arrays of strings in nopython mode?
Alternatively, could I somehow convert strings to numbers which numba would recognise?

I have to run certain loops on an array of strings (a column from a pandas dataframe); if I could use numba the code would be substantially faster.

I have come up with this minimal example to show what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

x=np.array(['some','text','this','is'])

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def numba_str(txt):
    x=0
    for i in xrange(txt.size):
        if txt[i]=='text':
            x += 1
    return x

print numba_str(x)
```

The error I get is:

```
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Undeclared ==([char x 4], str)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Judging purely from error it seems that you compare the whole array/list with string somehow. Are you sure that `txt[i]` is not the whole list.

Comment: @Andrey : yes, I'm sure. x[0]='some', x[1]= 'text', etc. You can easily see this disabling numba and adding 'print txt[i]' in the loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings are not yet supported by Numba (as of version 20.0). Actually, ["character sequences are supported, but no operations are available on them"](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.20.0/reference/numpysupported.html#scalar-types).

Indeed, a possible workaround is to interpret characters as numbers. For ASCII characters this is straightforward, see the Python `ord` and `chr` functions. However, already for your minimal example, you end with functions that are a lot less readable:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

x=np.array(['some','text','this','is'])

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def numba_str(txt):
    x=0
    for i in xrange(txt.shape[0]):
        if (txt[i,0]==116 and  # 't'
            txt[i,1]==101 and  # 'e'
            txt[i,2]==120 and  # 'x'
            txt[i,3]==116):    # 't'
            x += 1
    return x

print numba_str(x.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, x.itemsize))
```

Comment: I have managed to avoid the problem in one case because the text field was the primary key of a database table, so I created another, numerical, primary key outside of Numba and used that in my Numba function. However this is not applicable to all circumstances.

Comment: this answer is outdated. numba now supports `str`

Answer (score 13):

numba now supports `str` (since version 0.41)

Comment: Do you know when str.encode() will be supported?