# Add leading zeros based on condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 million rows. Let's say the dataframe looked like below:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Random": "86 7639103627 96 32 1469476501".split()})
>>> df
       Random
0          86
1  7639103627
2          96
3          32
4  1469476501
```

Note that the `Random` column is stored as a string.

If the number in column Random has fewer than 9 digits, I want to add leading zeros to make it 9 digits. If the number has 9 or more digits, I want to add leading zeros to make it 20 digits.

what I have done is this:

```
for i in range(0,len(df['Random'])):
      if len(df['Random'][i]) < 9:
          df['Random'][i]=df['Random'][i].zfill(9)
      else:
           df['Random'][i]=df['Random'][i].zfill(20)
```

Since the number of rows is over 5 million, this process takes a lot of time! (performance was 5it/sec. Tested using tqdm, estimated time of completion was in days!).

Is there an easier and faster way of performing this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need vectorize this; select the columns using a boolean index and use `.str.zfill()` on the resulting subsets:

```
# select the right rows to avoid wasting time operating on longer strings
shorter = df.Random.str.len() < 9
longer = ~shorter
df.Random[shorter] = df.Random[shorter].str.zfill(9)
df.Random[longer] = df.Random[longer].str.zfill(20)
```

Note: I did not use `np.where()` because we wouldn't want to double the work. A vectorized `df.Random.str.zfill()` is faster than looping over the rows, but doing it twice still takes more time than doing it just once for each set of rows.

Speed comparison on 1 million rows of strings with values of random lengths (from 5 characters all the way up to 30):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np, pandas as pd

In [2]: import platform; print(platform.python_version_tuple(), platform.platform(), pd.__version__, np.__version__, sep="\n")
('3', '7', '3')
Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
0.24.2
1.16.4

In [3]: !sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz

In [4]: from random import choices, randrange

In [5]: def randvalue(chars="0123456789", _c=choices, _r=randrange):
   ...:     return "".join(_c(chars, k=randrange(5, 30))).lstrip("0")
   ...:

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Random": [randvalue() for _ in range(10**6)]})

In [7]: %%timeit
   ...: target = df.copy()
   ...: shorter = target.Random.str.len() < 9
   ...: longer = ~shorter
   ...: target.Random[shorter] = target.Random[shorter].str.zfill(9)
   ...: target.Random[longer] = target.Random[longer].str.zfill(20)
   ...:
   ...:
825 ms ± 22.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: target = df.copy()
   ...: target.Random = np.where(target.Random.str.len()<9,target.Random.str.zfill(9),target.Random.str.zfill(20))
   ...:
   ...:
929 ms ± 69.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(The `target = df.copy()` line is needed to make sure that each repeated test run is isolated from the one before.)

Conclusion: on 1 million rows, using `np.where()` is about 10% slower.

However, using `df.Row.apply()`, [as proposed by jackbicknell14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57857153/), beats either method *by a huge margin*:

```
In [9]: def fill_zeros(x, _len=len, _zfill=str.zfill):
   ...:     # len() and str.zfill() are cached as parameters for performance
   ...:     return _zfill(x, 9 if _len(x) < 9 else 20)

In [10]: %%timeit
    ...: target = df.copy()
    ...: target.Random = target.Random.apply(fill_zeros)
    ...:
    ...:
299 ms ± 2.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That's about 3 times faster!

Comment: It would be faster to just negate shorter in the first clause of your `longer` condition rather than use the slow string accessor again.

Comment: @user3483203: no, because then `len() == 9` is included. This causes the numbers just zfilled to length 9 to be filled out to 20 digits.

Comment: Then calculate the mask before you make the first assignment.

Comment: @user3483203: that still won't exclude rows that *already* started at exactly 9 digits long.

Comment: He has clarified that he does want to pad exactly length 9 to 20. Even so, if that was not the case, it would still be faster to make shorter `<= 9` (barring a large discrepancy of exactly length 9 strings) and do a bit of extra work to make the second mask calculation much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Let us do `np.where` combine with `zfill`, alternative you can check with `str.pad`

```
df.Random=np.where(df.Random.str.len()<9,df.Random.str.zfill(9),df.Random.str.zfill(20))
df
Out[9]: 
                 Random
0             000000086
1  00000000007639103627
2             000000096
3             000000032
4  00000000001469476501
```

Comment: I can see two issues: you are doing double work, all rows, regardless of length, are padded out to 9 and 20 characters, and `np.where()` then selects from either set of rows, and columns of length 9 are padded out to length 20. The latter is a flaw in the code the OP posted too.

Answer (score 3):

I used 'apply' combined with the fill_zeros function written below to get a run time of 603ms over a dataframe of 1,000,000 rows.

```
data = {
    'Random': [str(randint(0, 100_000_000)) for i in range(0, 1_000_000)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def fill_zeros(x):
    if len(x) < 9:
        return x.zfill(9)
    else:
        return x.zfill(20)

%timeit df['Random'].apply(fill_zeros)

603 ms ± 1.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Compared to:

```
%timeit np.where(df.Random.str.len()<9,df.Random.str.zfill(9),df.Random.str.zfill(20))
1.57 s ± 6.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed (suprisingly) faster. Twice as fast, in fact.

Comment: You can also use `return x.zfill(9 if len(x) < 9 else 20)`.

Comment: And to really squeeze every last drop out of a pure Python function, avoid global and attribute lookups by caching those as parameters: `def fill_zeros(x, _len=len, _zfill=str.zfill): return _zfill(x, 9 if _len(x) else 20)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about efficiency, string operations are one of the common "gotchas" with Pandas, since while they *are* vectorized (in that you can apply them to an entire Series in one go), that does *not* mean that they are more efficient than looping, and this is one example where looping is actually going to be faster than using the string accessor, which tends to be more for convenience than speed.

When in doubt, make sure you time functions on your actual data, since something you think may be clunky and slow may be faster than something that looks clean!

---

I'm going to propose a very basic looping function that I think will beat any approach using the string accessor.

```
def loopy(series):
    return pd.Series(
        (
            el.zfill(9) if len(el) < 9 else el.zfill(20)
            for el in series
        ),
        name=series.name,
    )

# to compare more fairly with the apply version
def cache_loopy(series, _len=len, _zfill=str.zfill):
    return pd.Series(
      (_zfill(el, 9 if _len(el) < 9 else 20) for el in series), name=series.name)
```

---

Now let's check the timings, using the code provided by Martijn above and `simple_benchmark`.

***Functions***

```
def loopy(series):
    series.copy()    # not necessary but just to make timings fair
    return pd.Series(
        (
            el.zfill(9) if len(el) < 9 else el.zfill(20)
            for el in series
        ),
        name=series.name,
    )

def str_accessor(series):
    target = series.copy()
    mask = series.str.len() < 9
    unmask = ~mask
    target[mask] = target[mask].str.zfill(9)
    target[unmask] = target[unmask].str.zfill(20)
    return target

def np_where_str_accessor(series):
    target = series.copy()
    return np.where(target.str.len()<9,target.str.zfill(9),target.str.zfill(20))

def fill_zeros(x, _len=len, _zfill=str.zfill):
    # len() and str.zfill() are cached as parameters for performance
    return _zfill(x, 9 if _len(x) < 9 else 20)

def apply_fill(series):
    series = series.copy()
    return series.apply(fill_zeros)

def cache_loopy(series, _len=len, _zfill=str.zfill):
    series.copy()
    return pd.Series(
      (_zfill(el, 9 if _len(el) < 9 else 20) for el in series), name=series.name)
```

***Setup***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import choices, randrange
from simple_benchmark import benchmark

def randvalue(chars="0123456789", _c=choices, _r=randrange):
    return "".join(_c(chars, k=randrange(5, 30))).lstrip("0")

fns = [loopy, str_accessor, np_where_str_accessor, apply_fill, cache_loopy]
args = { 2**i: pd.Series([randvalue() for _ in range(2**i)]) for i in range(14, 21)}

b = benchmark(fns, args, 'Series Length')

b.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
df.Random.str.zfill(9).where(df.Random.str.len() < 9, df.Random.str.zfill(20))
```