# numba.vectorize - Unsupported array dtype

Tags: python, pandas, numba

I'm new to `numba` and can't seem to figure the arguments to pass to `vectorize`. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
test = [x for x in range(10)]
test2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'test': test, 'test2': test2})
test_df['test3'] = np.where(test_df['test'].values % 2 == 0,
                            test_df['test'].values, 
                            np.nan)


  test  test2   test3   test4
0    0      a     0.0     0.0
1    1      a     NaN     NaN
2    2      a     2.0     4.0
3    3      b     NaN     NaN
4    4      b     4.0    16.0
5    5      c     NaN     NaN
6    6      c     6.0    36.0
7    7      c     NaN     NaN
8    8      c     8.0    64.0
9    9      c     NaN     NaN
```

The task is create a new column based on the following logic, first based on standard `pandas`:

```
def nonnumba_test(row):
    if row['test2'] == 'a':
        return row['test'] * row['test3']
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Use `apply`; I understand I can accomplish this much faster using `np.where` and the `.values` attribute of the `Series` objects, but want to test this against `numba`.

```
test_df.apply(nonnumba_test, axis=1)

0    0.0
1    NaN
2    4.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Next, when I try to use the `numba.vectorize` decorator

```
@numba.vectorize()
def numba_test(x, y, z):
    if x == 'a':
        return y * z
    else:
        return np.nan
```

I get the following error

```
numba_test(test_df['test2'].values, 
           test_df['test'].values, 
           test_df['test3'].values)

ValueError: Unsupported array dtype: object
```

I imagine I need to specify the return type in the `signature` argument, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The problem** is that `numba` does not easily support strings ([see here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/types.html) and [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056337/python-can-numba-work-with-arrays-of-strings-in-nopython-mode)).

**The solution** is to handle the boolean logic `if x=='a'` outside the numba decorated function.  Modifying your example (both `numba_test` and the input argument) as follows produces the desired output (everything above the last two blocks in your example is unchanged):

```
from numba import vectorize, float64, int64, boolean

#@vectorize() will also work here, but I think it's best practice with numba to specify types.
@vectorize([float64(boolean, int64, float64)])
def numba_test(x, y, z):
    if x:
        return y * z
    else:
        return np.nan

# now test it...
# NOTICE the boolean argument, **not** string!
numba_test(test_df['test2'].values =='a', 
           test_df['test'].values, 
           test_df['test3'].values)
```

Returns:

```
array([  0.,  nan,   4.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

as desired.

**Final note**: you'll see that I specify types in the `vectorize` decorator above.  Yes, it's a bit annoying, but I think it's best practice because it spares you headaches *exactly* like this one: if you had specified the types, you would have been unable to find the string type, and that would have solved it.

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately, this means another "loop" in NumPy to convert to bool, which reduces the run time advantage, if any.